# Star Wars Sequel Trilogy - What's the astropolitical layout of the galaxy?

Tags: star-wars

Note-If anyone could come up with a more fitting title it would be greatly appreciated

I'm very confused to the relative size and power of the factions in the sequel trilogy. Original trilogy has large Empire, small Rebellion. Prequels have large Republic, medium sized Separatists.

I have no clue how big the New Republic is, how it stands compared to the First Order. I have no clue how big the First Order is. Can someone please clarify this for me?

Comment: New trilogy has big Republic, rump Empire, unknown First Order

Comment: First Order is leftover Imperial Militants who couldn't stand that the Empire was down to nothing after the Emporer's 'death'. They rebuilt what military forces they could and then built Starkiller base. So essentially, like @Valorum said, there's essentially three factions. The big but fragile Republic, downtrodden and zoned-in Empire (remnants), and whatever size the First Order is (extremists who fawned after Vader and Palpatine's way of doing things)

Comment: @MissouriSpartan - Not quite true. Some of the remnants of the Imperial Fleet headed into the uncharted space to the Galactic East where they encountered the *Mysterious First Order* and were basically ensnared

Comment: @Valorum, you're right. Although I thought that was the Galactic West?

Comment: About the title: Perhaps "astropolitical" instead of "geopolitical"? "Geo" means "Earth," but "Astro" means "Star."

Comment: @MissouriSpartan - Whichever one is on the left.

Answer (score 1):

First Order, Size and Strength:
According to the last book in the Aftermath series by Chuck Wendig, The first order stemmed from Imperial remnants around the time of the "Battle Of Jakku". The Imperial leaders, led by some Moffs, And Hux's father, Kidnapped and brainwashed children to do work for them, though this was after concluding stormtroopers were inadequate by leaving them planetside with little to nothing in the way of provisions to test their durability, leading to shell shocked and often unstable troopers. The children were demonstrated to the current Imperial leader who was being used purely as a figurehead without her knowing, after she found out about the plot. In the wreckage of the battle of Jakku, The Children, Admiral Sloane, Hux's Father and Hux, Left for wildspace.

We also know that in the Star Wars Battlefront II campaign, in the Resurrection levels, that the first order grew to become very powerful, with the capabilities of leveling entire planets, kidnapping more children to enslave to their cause, and in a cutscene, The numbers on the size are apparently huge due to the astonished gasps the characters give.

In the last Jedi, The Finalizer is another show of apparent strength, with its massive size, it must be able to carry at the very least a couple hundred thousand.

And of course, Imperial remnants were probably added to the First Orders military, making it even stronger. We even see AT-AT's at the battle of Crait, which goes to further emphasize this Idea.

Comment: I am not 100% sure about the size of the Republic though, everything I have read and seen does not give me an adequate idea to how large they actually might be in canon.

Comment: They've got the biggest cannon in the galaxy, so they must be pretty big. d;

Comment: @aslum They don't have the biggest canon anymore tho.